# Is there a reliable way to get file sharing between macOS Mojave systems running?

Tags: macos-mojave, file-sharing, fileshare

Subject says it all. I have two 10.14.6 macOS Mojave systems, both early 2019 Macs but I am failing to get the home directories of users on one shared and available to those same users on the other.

Only one thing works, from one system I can get sharing to work form a single user (admin user), but the other way around the same doesn't work and other users do not work in any direction.

Comment: It might be better to ask this at https://apple.stackexchange.com.

Comment: My bad. I thought I had.